# JS Joi Validation fails on string length

Tags: javascript, validation, joi

After spending almost 2 days to investigate why the validation is not working, I've got to a point. Basically I found out that if my string has more than 40 chars, the validation will fail. If it has 40 or bellow it will work.

So now I am using `validator.joi.string()` but I also try to fix this issue with : `validator.joi.string().min(0).max(500)` but it doesn't seem to work.

Any solution to this?

Comment: Can you break it down to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please?

Answer (score 6):

Just was testing. Sorry for the wrong formatting.

But It does work fine.

```
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');

const schema = Joi.object({
    username: Joi.string()
        .min(3)
        .max(100)
        .required(),
})


schema.validate({ username: 'abc' });
// -> { value: { username: 'abc' } }

schema.validate({});
// -> { value: {}, error: '"username" is required' }

// Also -

async function run(){
  const value = await schema.validateAsync({ username: 'abcedeedsdsd sfdfghgdf sgfdghsfdsfdjgsfdgs shgdfshgdbshgdf sdhghsjfgfkhgj' });
  console.log(value)
}

run();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your validator initiation. If that fine then the following will work.

```
Joi.string().max(10)
```